# iOS: Memory leak when try to scale the UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

Memory leak happens when I run the code below. I even haven't used or hold the `newImage` object.

```
for image in imageArray {
    autoreleasepool {
        let newImage = image.scalingWith(targetSize: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))
    }
}
```

and here are the scale method in `UIImage` extension:

```
func scaleWith(targetSize: CGSize, backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor
    .white) -> UIImage? {
    let imageSize = size
    var scaleFactor: CGFloat = 0.0
    let scaledWidth = targetSize.width
    let scaledHeight = targetSize.height
    var thumbnailPoint = CGPoint.zero

    if imageSize.equalTo(targetSize) { return self }

    let widthFactor = targetSize.width / imageSize.width
    let heightFactor = targetSize.height / imageSize.height

    if widthFactor > heightFactor {
        scaleFactor = heightFactor
        thumbnailPoint.x = (targetSize.width - scaleFactor * imageSize.width) * 0.5;
    } else {
        scaleFactor = widthFactor
        thumbnailPoint.y = (targetSize.height - scaleFactor * imageSize.height) * 0.5;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: scaledWidth, height: scaledHeight))

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scaledWidth, height: scaledHeight)
    context!.setFillColor(backgroundColor.cgColor)
    context!.fill(bounds)

    var thumbnailRect = CGRect.zero
    thumbnailRect.size.width = imageSize.width * scaleFactor;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = imageSize.height * scaleFactor;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint

    draw(in: thumbnailRect)
    let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resultImage
}
```

Could anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is fairly easy to run this code in the Instruments with memory leaks enabled. Also, you need to run it on device as running it on simulator will produce wrong result. There was a bug in Xcode that it was not releasing objects when in debug mode and console was used.

So again: run in instruments on device. Code looks good, there should not be memory leak. 
Also is that autoreleasepool needed there considering the code inside that loop?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the device to test the code, but not Instruments. So I tried again with Instruments. It seems everything is OK now. Thank you again.